# select option is not working in react js code

Tags: reactjs, select-options

I'm using react js but I have a problem select option is not opening.
When I click Button it does not work.
I can't understand what is the problem. I have checked almost everything that I can do.
here is the code

```js
export default function Feature({ type }) {
    return (
        <div className="feature">
        {type && (
          <div className="category">
            <span>{type === "movie" ? "Movies" : "Series"}</span>    
            <select name="genre" id="genre">
              <option>Genre</option>
              <option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
              <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
              <option value="crime">Crime</option>
              <option value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
              <option value="historical">Historical</option>
              <option value="horror">Horror</option>
              <option value="romance">Romance</option>
              <option value="sci-fi">Sci-fi</option>
              <option value="thriller">Thriller</option>
              <option value="western">Western</option>
              <option value="animation">Animation</option>
              <option value="drama">Drama</option>
              <option value="documentary">Documentary</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        )}
```

This is my home component

```js
import "./home.scss";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar/Navbar";
import Feature from "../components/featured/Feature"


export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="home">
           <Navbar />
           <Feature type="movie" />
           
          
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please add the part of code when you receive the props in you Feature components and the way you handle it .

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing tags probably in your code:

```js
export default function Feature({ type }) {
    return (
        <div className="feature">
        {type && (
          <div className="category">
            <span>{type === "movie" ? "Movies" : "Series"}</span>    
            <select name="genre" id="genre">
              <option>Genre</option>
              <option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
              <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
              <option value="crime">Crime</option>
              <option value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
              <option value="historical">Historical</option>
              <option value="horror">Horror</option>
              <option value="romance">Romance</option>
              <option value="sci-fi">Sci-fi</option>
              <option value="thriller">Thriller</option>
              <option value="western">Western</option>
              <option value="animation">Animation</option>
              <option value="drama">Drama</option>
              <option value="documentary">Documentary</option>
            </select>
          </div>)}
          </div>)};
```